# In AWS Lambda Function my JSON object is getting corrupted

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, parsing, lambda

I am trying to save a simple JSON object into MongoDb database using AWS Lambda. I am sending the json `{"first_name":"Arun","last_name":"KS","department":"Student","user_name":"arunmails91@gmail.com","user_password":"Arunks@9633","confirm_password":"Arunks@9633","email":"arunmails91@gmail.com","contact_no":"9633047332"}`

However, In logs I can see that it is getting converted to

> at [Source: (String)"{first_name=Arun, last_name=KS, department=Student, user_name=arunmails91@gmail.com, user_password=Arunks@9633, confirm_password=Arunks@9633, email=arunmails94@gmail.com, contact_no=9633047332}"; line: 1, column: 3]

PROBLEM: I don't want that conversion to happen. Java code is written to handle proper json. Since this unwanted conversion is happening, my code is breaking. How I can avoid that conversion in Lambda and what is the reason for auto conversion.

My code is

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
public class CognitoSaveUser {
    public Boolean saveNewUserInDB (Object jsonUserDetails,Context context) {

        Boolean processStatus = false;
        context.getLogger().log("Inside the method saveNewUserInDB");
        try {
            MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
                       "mongodb+srv://username:password@clusterdemo-07.mongodb.net/DBname");
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("EclipseCognitoTest");
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("UserProfile");

            context.getLogger().log("DB Connection is OK");
            JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
            JsonParser  parser  = factory.createParser(jsonUserDetails.toString());

            Document doc = new Document();

            String docKey = "";
            String docValue = "";

            while(!parser.isClosed()){
                JsonToken jsonToken = parser.nextToken();

                if(JsonToken.FIELD_NAME.equals(jsonToken)){
                    docKey = parser.getCurrentName();

                    jsonToken = parser.nextToken();
                    docValue = parser.getValueAsString();
                    doc.append(docKey, docValue);
                    context.getLogger().log("Key->"+docKey+"-value->"+docValue);
                    } 
                }
         collection.insertOne(doc);
         processStatus = true;
         context.getLogger().log("processStatus="+processStatus);

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return processStatus;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now. The above issue is because I was using a deprecated Lambda API and there were few mistakes in usage of Lambda.

With below code I am able to save a JSON payload in to Atlas MongoDB instance.

If you run this inside an VPC, make sure necessary network policies are in place. Otherwise you will receive a Socket error in logs and below error in Eclipse console.

> ==================== INVOCATION ERROR ==================== com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Read
>   timed out

My complete code, I am sure this will help others who are new to Lambda and MongoDB Atlas.

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaCreateUser implements RequestHandler<RegistrationRequest, String> {


    public String handleRequest(RegistrationRequest input, Context context) {

        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input.getFirstName());
        Boolean userStatus = false;

        try {

        CognitoSaveUser newUser = new CognitoSaveUser();
        userStatus = newUser.saveNewUserInDB(input, context);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return "Hello from Lambda-"+userStatus.toString();
    }

}
```

Don't forget to create the 2 constructors at the end of this bean class. I lost hours without those.
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

```
public class RegistrationRequest {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String department;
    String userName;
    String userPassword;
    String confirmPassword;
    String email;
    String contactNo;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }
    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }
    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }
    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }
    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }
    public RegistrationRequest(String firstName, String lastName, String department, String userName, String userPassword, String confirmPassword, String email, String contactNo) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.department = department;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
        this.email = email;
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }
    public RegistrationRequest() {
    }

}
```

The final class which will do all the magic. Don't forget to put the correct username, password and dbname for MongoDB URI

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
public class CognitoSaveUser {


    public Boolean saveNewUserInDB (RegistrationRequest jsonUserDetails,Context context) {

        Boolean processStatus = false;
        context.getLogger().log("Inside the method saveNewUserInDB");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {

            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonUserDetails);
            context.getLogger().log("Converted JSOn String->"+jsonString);

            JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
            JsonParser  parser  = factory.createParser(jsonString);

            Document doc = new Document();
            String docKey = "";
            String docValue = "";

            while(!parser.isClosed()){
                JsonToken jsonToken = parser.nextToken();

                if(JsonToken.FIELD_NAME.equals(jsonToken)){
                    docKey = parser.getCurrentName();
                    jsonToken = parser.nextToken();
                    docValue = parser.getValueAsString();
                    doc.append(docKey, docValue);
                    context.getLogger().log("Key->"+docKey+"-value->"+docValue);
                    } 
                }

            MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
                       "mongodb+srv://username:password@clusterdemo-07d17.mongodb.net/dbname");
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("EclipseCognitoTest");
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("UserProfile");

            context.getLogger().log("DB Connection is OK");
            collection.insertOne(doc);

            processStatus = true;
            context.getLogger().log("processStatus="+processStatus);

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return processStatus;
    }


}
```